# network applications throwing "Servname not supported for ai_socktype"

Tags: networking, services

Why are some network application failing with this error message?

```
$ whois example.com
getaddrinfo(whois.verisign-grs.com): Servname not supported for ai_socktype
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can occur when, due to misconfiguration, an unprivileged user does not have read access to `/etc/services`. Check with:

```bsh
ls -l /etc/services
```

It should look like `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root ...`

The file should be installed from the *Priority: important* package `netbase` and have exactly these permissions. If not, fix it with:

```bsh
sudo chown root:root /etc/services
sudo chmod 644 /etc/services
```

*Nothing about the files contents is confidential or expected to change often. The file lists [IANA-registered](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) or common protocol port number associations for TCP, UDP, DCCP, and SCTP.*